# Dividing up items based on quantity

Tags: php

We have a custom dispatch system where we have orders, if the total quantity within the order exceeds 2 then we need to split the contents over two orders. So for instance...

Order contains:

- Item A x2
- Item B x2

I need to move Item B to a second order.

Another example would be:

- Item A x4

I would need to move 2 items to a second order so I'm left with Item A x2 in one output and the same in another output.

I'm using the following to loop through the items and quantities within an order.

```
$total_products = array();
foreach($products as $product){

  $product_id = $product['sellable']['id'];
  $product_quantity = $product['quantity'];
  $product_price = $product['price_per_unit'];

  array_push($total_products, array($product_id, $product_quantity, $product_price));
}
```

How can I total up the items in that order - as soon as any of the quantities hit 2, can I move those to a second array? Is using multiple arrays the best approach for this?

This is an example of an array that's been generated (this can be variable):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 39235995
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2.81
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 39236029
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2.952
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 39236015
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3.333
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 39235997
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2.667
        )

)
```

Comment: Why are you using `array_push()` and not `$total_products[] = …`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure this out by using the following, this gives me the separate parcels I needed:

```
// Add the product info we need into a new array
$total_products = array();
foreach($products as $product){

  $product_id = $product['sellable']['id'];
  $product_quantity = $product['quantity'];
  $product_price = $product['price_per_unit'];

  $total_products[] = array('id' => $product_id, 'quantity' => $product_quantity, 'price' => $product_price);
}

// Separate out the quantities for each product, one per array
$resultArr = [];
foreach($total_products as $item){
  for($i = 0; $i < $item['quantity']; $i++){
      $resultArr[] = array(
        'id' => $item['id'],
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => $item['price'],
      );
  }
}

// Divide up into the correct amount of parcels
$parcel_size = 2;
$parcels = array_chunk($resultArr, $parcel_size);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `$product_quantity` is always a positive integer. But maybe you would like to check that before proceeding, like so:

```php
$product_quantity = $product['quantity']; // this is already in your code
if (!is_int($product_quantity) || $product_quantity < 1) {
    // handle the invalid data
}
```

Now that we are sure that we only deal with positive integers, we can check in each iteration that we don't exceed the number of allowed items per order:

```php
$total_products = array();

$product_per_order = 0;

foreach($products as $product){

  $product_id = $product['sellable']['id'];
  $product_quantity = $product['quantity'];
  $product_price = $product['price_per_unit'];

  while ($product_quantity > 2) {
    // handle delivery with 2 products of type $product_id
    $product_quantity -= 2;
  }

  if ($product_quantity <= 0) { // We delivered all of what was ordered
    continue;
  }

  $product_per_order += $product_quantity;

  if ($product_per_order > 2) {
     // handle more deliveries
     $product_per_order = 0; // initialize
  }

  $total_products[] = array($product_id, $product_quantity, $product_price);
}
```

This is just an outline for a way to follow the number of products, you should improve it and self-tailor it to your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this fulfils the requirement of splitting the products into multiple orders, but still retaining the product data in each:

```
$orders = [];
$i = 0;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    foreach (array_fill(0, ceil($product['quantity'] / 2), $product) as $splitProduct) {
        $splitProduct['quantity'] = min(2, $product['quantity']);
        $orders[$i][] = $splitProduct;

        $total = array_reduce($orders[$i], function ($carry, $product) {
            return $carry + $product['quantity'];
        }, 0);

        if ($total >= 2) {
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Example 1:

Input:

```
$products[] = ['sellable' => ['id' => 1], 'quantity' => 4, 'price_per_unit' => 0];
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sellable] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                        )

                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price_per_unit] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sellable] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                        )

                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price_per_unit] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Example 2:

Input:

```
$products[] = ['sellable' => ['id' => 1], 'quantity' => 2, 'price_per_unit' => 0];
$products[] = ['sellable' => ['id' => 2], 'quantity' => 2, 'price_per_unit' => 0];
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sellable] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                        )

                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price_per_unit] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sellable] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                        )

                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price_per_unit] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems close but I probably didn't explain it enough. The parcels need to be split into no more than a total quantity of 2. So that can be a mix of products or all the same product, but no more than a total quantity of two in one parcel. I just tried it with Item A x3, Item B x1, Item C x1 & Item D x1 (so a total quantity of 6). It created an array with Item A x2, Item A x2, Item B x1, Item C x1 and Item D x1.

I need it to be Item A x2 (parcel 1), Item A x1 & Item B x1 (parcel 2), Item C x1 & Item D x1 (parcel 3). So that's created 3 parcels.

Comment: @Rob I think your explanation was good, I just didn't test/think of those kinds of permutations :) I'll see if I can hack around with it on my lunch break and get it working.

Comment: Thanks so much, I've updated the question with my array that I'm working with.